# Run scripts from database

Tags: php

Is it possible for a PHP script to insert a block of code into a database, and then some kind of daemon sees that it was put in, and then runs the code? Kind of like a cron job, or a job queue.

Comment: Putting code into a database is usually a bad idea. Better to have the code be on the daemon side, and simply pass through what parameters you want that code to operate on.

Comment: think of it this way: what if someone hacks his way to your database and run arbitrary code?

Comment: Okay, but what if I needed it in a queue?

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can do it. The code should be stored in a TEXT column and then you could evaluate it with `eval`: http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

This is not a very good idea for several reasons: code stored in a database is not under version control, and the security implications are pretty severe. Most job queue systems store a "job type" and "job parameters" instead of executable code. The job type could be the name of a file to include, or the name of a class to instantiate in an OOP setting. Then you would call a specific function defined there, passing in the parameters.

The job parameters can be any PHP data structure if you use the `serialize` function to turn it into a string first. http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php